# How to save ids in the cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am using will_paginate to list a huge ammont of files in different pages. I also have a check_box in order to choose files for the futher analysis.

controller:

```
@files = FileDB.search(search_string).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

view:

```
  <button type="button" id="check_all">Check/Uncheck all</button>
 <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'analyse' do %>Analyse<% end %>

    <% @filess.each do |file| %>
    <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td><%= file.name %></p>
    lala...
```

My problem is that I can choose the files which are situated in one page.So by clicking on "check/uncheck all" it checks not all available files, but files of this specific page. I would like to be able to check different files from different pages together.

Example: 10 files on the page 1, 4 files on the page 2. I want to check 5 files from page one and all files from page 2 and then by clicking on the buttom "Analyse", those 9 files have to be analyzed together, so the checkbox should remember different files from different pages

I know it is possible to save ids in the cookies, but I have found nothing in internet how to do it. I need just a small example

Thanks in advance

edit:
or maybe there is an alternative to the will_paginate that uses POST?

edit2: according to Muntasim

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
               $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
            </script>
            <script src="/assets/rails.validations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/assets/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var checkedIds = $.cookie('checked_file_ids');
                $('p td input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
                   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                       checkedIds.push($(this).val())
                   }
                    else  {
                       checkedIds.splice(checkedIds.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
                   }
                    $.cookie('checked_file_ids', checkedIds);
                })

           </script>

          <%= form_for Group.new, url: what_to_do_files_path ,method: :get ,:validate => true do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
          <%=f.text_field :group_name, placeholder: "Group Name" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          </div>

          <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'analyse' do %>Analyse<% end %>
          <button type="button" id="check_all" class="btn"> Check/Uncheck All</button>

          <% @files.each do |file| %>
           <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id , false %></td><%= file.name %></p>

            <%end%>

    <%end%>
```

And in a controller:

```
def what_to_do
    ids_to_compare = cookies['checked_file_ids']
end
```

But ids_to_compare is empty

Comment: You should use `session` in this case instead of cookies. Something like `session[:file_db][:checked_ids]` which would contain all the checked ids of FileDB objects.

Comment: @MrYoshiji and that is all? without javascript and so on?

Comment: It depends on your needs, javascript here would be interesting if you want to change pages (and save the selected IDs in the session) without reloading the page. Do you want me to post an example of a basic session storage with the FileDB IDs?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I want to change pages without reloading the page. And ot would be very nice if you could post an eample

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
cookies[:ids] = #All checked ids
```

And then to retrieve the ids you can easily call the cookie like this:

```
cookies[:ids]
```

Answer (score 1):

### if you want to use cookie:

use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Now put this  in the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkedIds = $.cookie('checked_file_ids');
$('p td input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       checkedIds.push($(this).val())
   }
    else  {
       checkedIds.splice(checkedIds.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
   }
    $.cookie('checked_file_ids', checkedIds);
})
    
 </script>
```

now when you need to compare them you can get the ids:  (likely in a controller)

```
ids_to_compare = cookies['checked_file_ids']
```

Comment: I have no idea how to pass to "VALUE" my checkd ids. It will not take place automatically and more over I will need to pass it several times while changing the pages

Comment: I posted your solution in edit2. I get an error, that the variable "cookie" is not defined

Comment: try ids_to_compare = cookies['checked_file_ids']

I missed s, it would be cookies['key'] not cookie['key']

Comment: I tried it and I wanted to look what IDS were save, so I typed puts(ids_to_compare) and it printed nothing, so it is empty

Comment: you can inspect in client side after setting the cookie. using console.log($.cookie('checked_file_ids'))

Comment: sorry, it is not working. I checked the boxes, then in the controller I typed system "log($.cookie('checked_file_ids'))" in order to inspect it, but it showed me an error that it was expecting ")" and otherwise I do not understand how I can inspect it in the way you tell mw

Comment: No,
After checking the check box, open the browser console and type `$.cookie('checked_file_ids')` then hit enter. You should see wht is set in the cookie

Comment: it tells me: undefined

Comment: Are you sure that your code is correct? U tried this: $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value'); and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Bro, please have a look to the plugin, I didnt run that code but I just mentioned the way. please debug it :)